# cURL not working with POST data

Tags: php, debugging, curl

I am trying to debug this, but I've had no luck. Am I sending the POST data correctly?

```
if (isset($_POST['chrisBox'])) {

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.associates.com/send-email-orders.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST['chrisBox']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$ex = curl_exec($curl);
echo 'email';
$email = true;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS requires an urlencoded string or an array as param. Read [PHP Manual curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php). Have changed your example, now it uses an urlencoded string.

```
if (isset($_POST['chrisBox'])) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.associates.com/send-email-orders.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'chrisBox=' . urlencode($_POST['chrisBox']));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    $ex = curl_exec($curl);
    echo 'email';
    $email = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The parameters sent in a `$_POST` request need to be in the form of -

```
key=value&foo=bar
```

You can use PHP's [http-build-query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function for this. It'll create a query string from an array.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
```

If you only want to pass one parameter, you'll still need to wrap it in an array or object.

```
$params = array(
  'stack'=>'overflow'
);

http_build_query($params);     // stack=overflow
```

Comment: I was thinking since it was part of a form, it was already encoded. This function above encodes the key->value relationship. Right?

Comment: @wow - Yes. It creates a *URL-encoded* query string. Any illegal URL characters will be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ex = curl_exec($process);
if ($ex === false)
{
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . @curl_error($process));
    // this will give you more info
    var_dump(curl_error($process));
}
```