# cURL - sending GET request using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I can't understand where i am doing wrong.

below is my code:

```
$message = "testing from the application.";
$mobile_number = ""; //hidden for security
$sender = ""; //hidden for security    
$ch = curl_init(""); //hidden for security, http://ip
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.php?username=&password=&number=$mobile_number&sender=$sender&type=0&message=$message");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

`curl_getinfo` return 0, and `$output` did't return anything, but the Document says if the request successful then the `$output` is 1101.

> I tested it in the postman, the result is ok.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.php?username=&password=&number=$mobile_number&sender=$sender&type=0&message=$message");` here you are passing the values are not? Also what `var_dump(echo $output);` and `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));` says?

Comment: hidden for security, but if i give some values there its work in postman. i already says what other two return.

Comment: You might need to url encode the values

Comment: what to use for encode?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Also you need to specify the POST true,AFAIK curl defaults to GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921867/curl-not-working-with-post-data

Comment: @Mihai i have a GET Request, and after i encode the url, its remain same.

Comment: Test it directly,use something like httpfox in firefox to see the headers and go to that url in the browser

Comment: I tested the url in gooogle postman, its work fine there, but  i don't know why the same url not working with PHP.

Comment: might be missing an / before api.php?

Comment: @Mihai, I got the problem, The message contain the spaces, so the url not working. how to encode the message so the space not a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your final comment, since the problem was due to the URL parameters not being url encoded, the simplest way to do so I think is like this:

```
$params = array(
    'message'  => "testing from the application.",
    'number'   => "", //hidden
    'sender'   => "", //hidden
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'type'     => 0,
);

$url = 'api.php?'. http_build_query($params);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

See [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) for more information.  It will safely encode the array into a string suitable for URL encoded HTTP POST requests, or for query string parameters.

When a `cURL` request fails, seeing everything returned by `curl_getinfo()` is helpful too.

In this case I would have thought the `HTTP` code would have been `400`, for bad request.  Also you call do `echo curl_error($ch);` for a human-readable error message.

Comment: i use same as you say but the message is `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 05:25:15 GMT Accept-Ranges: bytes Server: LiteSpeed Connection: close `

Comment: yes, it works, you miss to remove the space here after `?' . `in `'api.php?' . http_build_query($params);`