# Multiple input (q parameters) in Google Translate API , with PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

When we make a query to [Translate API][1]:

```
function curl($url, $post_array=false){ 
        $handle = curl_init();
        if (FALSE === $handle) 
            throw new Exception('failed to CURL initialize; '. __FILE__);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if($post_array) {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array );
        } 
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET'));
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        return $response;
}


var_dump ( curl("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2", ['key'=>$key, 'q[]'=>"hello", 'q[]'=>"world", 'source'=>"en", 'target'=>'ru']   ) );
```

ends in error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Required Text",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Required Text",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to send multiple `q` input texts?  As I see, the API doesn't allow `q[]` type arrays, instead it uses multiple `q` parameters. But in `php` we can't have same key multiple times in array...

Comment: The documentation `https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate` suggests that the parameter is simply `q` rather than `q[]` and you should repeat as often as required..

Comment: @RamRaider but php doesnt allow multiple same keys in array

Comment: Use a string rather than an array for `postfields` ?

Answer (score 1):

i believe this API supports JSON, and JSON supports arrays, so just do

```
function curl($url, array $post_array){ 
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_POST=>1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>json_encode($post_data),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Content-Type: application/json')
));
(...)
}
```

and call it like

```
var_dump ( curl("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
 ['key'=>$key, 'q'=>array("hello","world"),
 'source'=>"en", 'target'=>'ru']   ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the post fields. PHP offers `http_build_query`.

```php
function curl($url, $post_array=false){ 
        $handle = curl_init();
        if (FALSE === $handle) 
            throw new Exception('failed to CURL initialize; '. __FILE__);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if($post_array) {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array) );
        } 
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET'));
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        return $response;
}


var_dump ( curl("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2", ['key'=>$key, 'q'=> array("hello", "world"), 'source'=>"en", 'target'=>'ru']   ) );
```

Relevant are [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921867/curl-not-working-with-post-data).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, rather than using an array where there can not be repeated keys in the POSTFIELDS data array ( or any array in PHP ) you can supply a string for the POST data

My curl function

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL ){
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';    #<---- edit to suit
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


    $res=array(
        'response'  =>  NULL,
        'info'      =>  array( 'http_code' => 100 ),
        'headers'   =>  NULL,
        'errors'    =>  NULL
    );
    if( is_null( $url ) ) return (object)$res;

    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );



    /* Assign runtime parameters as options */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}
```

The configuration for the request:

```
$key='AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9oIhY8Q8xxxxx';

$url='https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2';
$arr=array( 'another', 'elephant', 'banana', 'woman' );

/* some translate parameters */
$params=array(
    'target'    =>  'fr',
    'format'    =>  'text',
    'source'    =>  'en',
    'model'     =>  'nmt'
);
/* the POST data */
$query=implode( '&', array( 
    sprintf( 'key=%s&q=%s',$key, implode( '&q=', $arr ) ), #query
    urldecode( http_build_query( $params ) ) #google params
));

$config=array(
    CURLOPT_POST        =>  true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  $query
);

$res=curl( $url, $config );
if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $res->response,true ) );
}
```

Appears to work OK and returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "un autre",
        "model": "nmt"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "l'éléphant",
        "model": "nmt"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "banane",
        "model": "nmt"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "femme",
        "model": "nmt"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others finding their way here and looking for how to translate multiple texts in a simple GET-request to the [Google Cloud Translation v2 REST API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate), you just need to add multiple `q=` parameters to your URL.

No need to mess around with cURL, just use `file_get_contents` and get on with your life. Something like this would do the job:

```
$texts = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello world'];

// Translate from english to swedish
$queryParams = [
    'target' => 'sv',
    'source' => 'en',
    'format' => 'text',
    'key'    => 'INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
];

// Now let's add q=<text> for each text
$queryString = http_build_query($queryParams);
foreach($texts as $t){
    $queryString .= '&q='.rawurlencode($t);
}

$url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?$queryString";

$responseBody = file_get_contents($url);
$responseArr = json_decode($responseBody, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my well-worked code snippet.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?API-KEY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$text1="The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex.";
$text2="this is second text example";
$params = array(
    'source'=>"en",
    'target'=> "sr-Latn",//serbian sr
    'format'=>"text",   
);
$post=implode('&',array(sprint_f('&q=%s',implode('&q=',array($text1,$text2)),urldecode(http_build_query($params)))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result=json_decode($response,true);
print_r($result['data']['translations']);
```